# opencv Python creating a loop to show images error

Tags: python, loops, opencv, show

I'm facing a problem with opencv in Python ( my python version is '3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]').
I'm trying to create a simple loop to show images contained in a file but it doesn't work and I don't understand the error message.

```
import os
import cv2
import download_JSON_file as djf
import image_process as imp

mat_data = djf.read_json("rad_cycles_4BPSK_AB_1536.json")

for k in range(len(mat_data)):
    # for each cycle ...
    #...
    #get the image name
    image = data_cycle["JPEG"]["JPEGFileName"] 

    path_4BPSK = "C:\\Users\\toto\\Documents\\SVN\\Radar_Object_Classification\\Clusters_data\\4BPSK_AB_1536\\"
    imagefullpath = path_4BPSK + image

    im = cv2.imread(imagefullpath)
    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cv2.namedWindow(str(k))
    cv2.imshow(str(k), im)



error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: after reading the image `im`, check what type of `im`. If `im` is not an array you will get this error. In your code what is `data_cycle` ?

Comment: As @JeruLuke suggest, check what type(im) returns. Also, print out imagefullpath to make sure it is the complete path to the image and that that image exists at that location.

Comment: On a side note, use the prefix r to your path, that is, path_4BPSK = r"C:\Users...". Using this saves you from adding the '\\' instead of a simple '\'

Comment: Thank you for your answers :). The problem comes from my path as you've noticed. Jeru Luke, data_cycle is a dictionnary that I extract from mat_data at each loop.